# Localisation error 'is translated here but not in default locale'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a `values-fr` and `values-es` and `values`.

The contents of `values` is english, but for each string I am getting this error:

```
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
```

it says: `"cancel" is translated here but is not found in default locale` and im not sure what this means.

`values/strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" tools:locale="en">

    <string translatable="false" name="app_name">Kendal Mintfest</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="itin_string">Itinerary</string>
    <string name="event_string">Events</string>
    <string name="info_string">Info!</string>
    <string name="filerText">Note: Turning this option on will show only results on the selected day on the hour you select.</string>
    <string-array name="time_filter_array">
        <item>Friday 30th August</item>
        <item>Saturday 31st August</item>
        <item>Sunday 1st September</item>
    </string-array>
    <color name="Pink">#EC008B</color>
    <string name="okay">Okay</string>
    <string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
</resources>
```

`values-fr/strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="action_settings">Paramètres</string>
    <string name="itin_string">itinéraire</string>
    <string name="event_string">Events</string>
    <string name="info_string">Info!</string>
    <string name="filerText">Remarque: Activer cette option affichera uniquement les r\ésultats le jour sélectionné à l\'heure que vous sélectionnez.</string>
    <string-array name="time_filter_array">
         <item>Vendredi 30 Août</item>
         <item>Samedi 31 Août</item>
         <item>dimanche 1er Septembre</item>
    </string-array>
    <color name="Pink">#EC008B</color>
    <string name="okay">OK</string>
    <string name="cancel">Annuler</string>
</resources>
```

`values-es/strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="action_settings">Configuración</string>
    <string name="itin_string">Itinerario</string>
    <string name="event_string">Events</string>
    <string name="info_string">Info!</string>
    <string name="filerText">Nota: Al activar esta opción sólo mostrará los resultados en el día seleccionado en la hora de seleccionar.</string>
    <string-array name="time_filter_array">
         <item>Viernes 30 de agosto</item>
         <item>Sábado 31 de agosto</item>
         <item>Domingo 01 de septiembre</item>
    </string-array>
    <color name="Pink">#EC008B</color>
    <string name="okay">Okay</string>
    <string name="cancel">Cancelar</string>
</resources>
```

Note: the error I stated above happens on ALL of the `values/strings.xml` lines

Comment: When are you changing your language??? After click event of any item?

Comment: Nope, in the strings files in the IDE (so different folders for different languages)

Comment: Ok... Have you set string for cancel in all string.xml file?

Comment: Yep, no errors from the files just the `values/strings.xml` file

Comment: Ok..that means you are not adding cancel string in values/strings.xml  folder

Comment: The problem is, it is in the `values/strings.xml` folder, they all are :/

Comment: can you post your string.xml file for all three folders?

Comment: Updated my OP, sorry for the delay - internet problems

Comment: have you set Locale.US as default?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Possibly not then

Comment: The XMLs should reside in the **/res** folder.

Comment: @JoopEggen the path of them is `/res/values-fr/strings.xml`, `/res/values/strings.xml` etc

Comment: I started getting similar problems when I updated my Mac OS to Maveriks (a java update came up as well).

Comment: to me this started to appear when I added <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en"> instead of just <resources> in the translation files. If you add  tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation" then it should disappear IMHO

Answer (score 6):

To me this started to appear when I added `<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en">` instead of just `<resources>` in the translation files. If you add  `tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation"` then it should disappear IMHO

Comment: Sure it disappear as Android Studio no longer check it. However, I noticed the resource definition is not available in code, and this error cannot be dismissed. Interestingly, building or launching debug works just fine, it's just the UI.

Answer (score 5):

Try the below two things:

1)check in strings file if the **key string name** being used is not misspelled in another translate, or copied twice in  same file.

2)Try **clean Project** and **rebuild project** 
  also perform restarting Android Studio with invalidate cache and restart.
  Android Studio >> File >> **Invalidate Caches/Restart...**

click on invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the string in the default locale. If you have it, try to delete the error line in the strings.xml and undo the deletion. If the string.xml is from a lib, delete the lib, sync, undo the deletion and sync again.

If the above step did not work, clean the project.