# name="string" is translated here but not found in the default locale

Tags: android, xml

I am declaring a string in the `strings.xml` and I am getting this error

here is my code:

```
<string name="date_picker_title">Hire Date</string>
<string name="new_employee">New Employee</string>
<string name="show_subtitle">Show Subtitle</string>
<string name="hide_subtitle">Hide Subtitle</string>
<string name="subtitle_format">%1$s crimes</string>
<string name="choose_menu">Choose a Menu Option</string>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have defined it string.xml(v21) it is not in the default xml ..define the tags in string.xml insted of string.xml(v21)

Comment: how to declare in default locale?

Comment: open the `res/values/strings.xml` file and declare it

Comment: the strings above declared are in the  res/values/strings.xml

Comment: Comment all strings which are showing error, and write strings by your self again. If strings were copied from somwhere, this could happen.

Comment: Resolved by rebuilding. :D

Comment: This is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821554/auth-client-using-bad-version-title-is-translated-here-but-not-found-in-defaul.

Answer (score 15):

Here in my case this just helped me:

1. Select the strings that are causing error.
2. Cut them.
3. Paste them again!

If it doesn't work for you, try adding the same strings to `strings.xml(v21)` file.
This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This is really fast solution, rather then 'Invalidate cache/restart' or 'clean/restart'!

Comment: Agreed, invalidate cache/restart/clean is takes time, thanks for providing this approach

Answer (score 11):

Try this. It solved the error in my case.

Go to **File -> Invalidate caches and restart .** In Android Studio Menu Bar

Comment: 2021 but it's still here... *File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ->* **Just restart** also works fine and faster than **Invalidate and Restart**.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the answers here, make sure your default `strings.xml` doesn't have a `tools:locale` attribute. Apparently, the default locale is assumed to be English always.

Answer (score 0):

**Build -> Clean Project**, after that **Build -> Rebuild Project** is work for me.