# Why do I keep getting this "is translated but not found in default local"?

Tags: android, android-resources

Why do I keep getting this "is translated but not found in default local"?  how can I solve it?

To my knowledge there are only two strings files I need to worry about the base one `valuse\strings.xml`  and `ja/strings.xml`  the first in English, the second in Japanese.

Comment: Where do you get this error message ?

Comment: I ran a lint check Analyze -> Inspect Code.  It shows that warning on both strings files.

Comment: Please check this, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027691/is-translated-here-but-not-found-in-default-locale-error-in-strings-xml-with-t?rq=1"

Comment: Try to remove String line and then  re-add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base string resources is inside `values` directory and the translation is inside `values-xx` or `values-xx-xXX` directory. For Japanese translation, the directory should be `values-jp`.

> Why do I keep getting this "is translated but not found in default
>   local"

It means that you have one or more strings in `values-xx` but the strings didn't exist in your `values` directory.