# Strings.xml gives a translation error whenever I try to add a new string resource

Tags: android, kotlin

The following is the only error message when i try to add a new string resource.

**NOTE** : I'm not doing any localization, there is only default values folder and adding string in strings.xml file only using **extract string** functionality of the android studio from my xml layout.

> "string_name" is translated here but not found in default locale.

Comment: Are you adding it to res/values/Strings.xml or something like res/values-en/Strings.xml? The former is the default locale file and the latter localizes for English.

Comment: Adding it to the res/values/strings.xml 
As I'm not doing any localization.

Comment: Anyway in strings.xml open the editor and click the Show All Locales combo box just to make sure

Comment: @mTak It only shows me Default Value. No other Translation language added.

Comment: Try this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780805/7831470

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did invalidate cache & restart, which solved my issue.

Comment: Yes That worked for me as well. Now it's not showing any error

Comment: I went to try this solution, but  I just closed Android Studio instead of Invalidate cache & restart.  That solved the problem for me.   Another thing that worked was to Analyze->Inspect Code and select the resource file giving you this problem.  In the inspection report you get, right click on the line with the error and select set properties.  In the dialog you can disable "multiple translations".  That solved the problem; but its problematic if you do want multiple translations.  I couldn't find a more convenient way to get to the properties associated with resources.

Answer (score 6):

In newer Android Studio (v.3) any string named with dot will cause "... is translated here but not found in default locale" error.
If your strings.xml has something like this

```
<string name="aaa.bbb">cccc</string>
```

you need to change it to

```
<string name="aaa_bbb">cccc</string>
```

Comment: Did you get around that  ?

Comment: The "dot" issue has been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120102995
I hope it gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

Syncing project with gradle files solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the resources file add this:

```
<resources tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Worked for me.

Comment: this is okay if you just have 1 language supported, but otherwise you'll run into an issue of not being warned of the missing string

Answer (score -4):

You should add a default string "string_name" to the strings.xml file.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
   <string name="string_name">default Test</string>
</resources>
```

Check you translate in Translations Editor

[image]

Comment: I'm not doing any localization.